# Why is UIButton appearing in a UIView, but origin is outside view?

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view controller laid out in Xcode 6 Beta 5/iOS 8 project (running it on iPhone 6 Plus simulator). The view controller has the following subviews placed and constrained in Interface Builder storyboard with AutoLayout constraints:

- Table view
- Search field
- Segmented control
- UIButton position to right of segmented view, constrained inset it from the superview trailing margin (by 7 points).

The view controller's view frame size is (414, 736) (dimensions of the *iPhone 6 Plus*).  However, when I print the frame of the inset UIButton mentioned above, it shows origin.x = 545. That's *way* to the right the right margin (414) of the screen in portrait orientation. Yet the button appears properly in the designed layout position on the screen just to the right of the segmented control.

If I try to position another view over the button, at x = 545, the overlaid view is not visible (because it's way off to the right screen, as I would expect the UIButton should also be). And I reduce the value X coordinate of the overlaid component to the sane origin.x position 350 or so, it appears on top the button.

Why is the UIButton's frame not matching the button's visible position? I printed all the constraints for the view controller's view  (below), but I don't see anything that accounts for the discrepancy there either.

What's going on?

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c509230 UISearchBar:0x7ff259cecf50.trailing == UIView:0x7ff25c5083d0.trailingMargin>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c509280 UISearchBar:0x7ff259cecf50.leading == UIView:0x7ff25c5083d0.leadingMargin>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c5092d0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ff25c5084c0]-(0)-[UISearchBar:0x7ff259cecf50]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c509320 UISegmentedControl:0x7ff259ce2960.trailing == UIButton:0x7ff259cde7f0.leading - 15>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c509370 UISegmentedControl:0x7ff259ce2960.leading == UITableView:0x7ff25a08f800.leading + 8>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c5093c0 V:[UISearchBar:0x7ff259cecf50]-(0)-[UISegmentedControl:0x7ff259ce2960]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c509410 UITableView:0x7ff25a08f800.bottom == UIView:0x7ff25c5083d0.bottomMargin - 44>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c509460 V:[UISegmentedControl:0x7ff259ce2960]-(10)-[UITableView:0x7ff25a08f800]>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c5094b0 UITableView:0x7ff25a08f800.leading == UIView:0x7ff25c5083d0.leadingMargin>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c509500 UITableView:0x7ff25a08f800.trailing == UIView:0x7ff25c5083d0.trailingMargin>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c509550 UIButton:0x7ff259cde7f0.centerY == UISegmentedControl:0x7ff259ce2960.centerY>
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7ff25c5095a0 UIButton:0x7ff259cde7f0.trailing == UIView:0x7ff25c5083d0.trailingMargin - 7>
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7ff259cf15d0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ff25c5084c0(0)]>
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7ff259cf1570 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ff25c5084c0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7ff25c5083d0 )>
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7ff259cf2550 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7ff25c5087d0(0)]>
<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7ff259cf24f0 _UILayoutGuide:0x7ff25c5087d0.bottom == UIView:0x7ff25c5083d0.bottom>

[ (0, 0), (414, 736) ] view.frame
pos:  (561, 122) clipboardButton.center
[ (0, 0), (414, 736) ] view.bounds
[ (545, 106), (32, 32) ] button.frame
[ (0, 0), (32, 32) ] button.bounds
```